# Distribution of wetland inflows to the wetland storage in WRSM-Pitman

Tags: hydrology, models

I’m working with the comprehensive wetland module in WRSM-Pitman (Bailey and Pitman, 2015) and reconstructing the water balance.
Apart from parameter differences, which proportion of upstream inflows always increases the wetland storage?

Answer (score 1):

Flows above the bankfull capacity of the river and adjusted by the Kin parameter always enters the wetland storage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).